# What does POSIX mean when it says stderr is expected to be open for reading and writing?

Tags: c, file, language-lawyer, posix, stderr

POSIX's page on [stderr, stdin, stdout - standard I/O streams](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) says this:

> The *stderr* stream is expected to be open for reading and writing.

How strong is "expected to be"? Is violating it Undefined Behavior? And whose responsibility is it, the system's or the application's?

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("feof is %d and ferror is %d\n", feof(stderr), ferror(stderr));
    printf("fgetc is %d\n", fgetc(stderr));
    printf("feof is %d and ferror is %d\n", feof(stderr), ferror(stderr));
}
```

When I run that without redirecting stderr (so it's pointing to my terminal just like stdin is), it immediately outputs this without waiting for any input:

```
feof is 0 and ferror is 0
fgetc is -1
feof is 0 and ferror is 1
```

Does that mean my system isn't POSIX-compliant?

Also, if it's my responsibility, then suppose I have a file with permissions `620`, and that I'm in the group but not the owner. Does this mean that `someprogram 2>saidfile` is Undefined Behavior, since you couldn't read from stderr no matter what in that case?

Comment: Traditionally, the `login` command (or the `getty` program run before `login`) would open the tty device for reading and writing as file descriptor 0 (standard input), and use `dup()` to create file descriptors 1 (standard output) and 2 (standard error).  Thus, the shell launched by `login` would probably have all three standard I/O descriptors that are readable and writable (but the I/O streams might not be as flexible).  I was not aware of the POSIX requirement; it was formally added in Issue 6 (POSIX 2004). It will be the responsibility of the system (shell) to provide a readable `stderr`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But even when FD 2 is open for reading and writing, trying to read from the `stderr` stream fails (if I want it to work, I have to use the FD directly). And that seems to be exactly what POSIX says isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: What's also weird is the note that "The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard", yet ISO C contains no such requirement as this.

Comment: I'm expanding a bit on where I think the requirement came from; I'm not able to account for it, and I'm puzzled about the specification that `stderr` (as distinct from 'standard error') is readable and writable.  Of course, you should be using a positioning operation (e.g. `fseek(stderr, 0L, SEEK_CUR)`) between reading and writing, or between writing and reading, for file streams.  I note that POSIX doesn't say anything about whether `stdin` or `stdout` need to be both readable and writable.  The requirement is in a POSIX extension section: [CX] ⌦ … ⌫ — it is a pure extension over standard C.

Comment: If there's nonconformance here, it seems like it's the fault of the C library, refusing to accept reads on stderr even when fd 2 is open for reading.  My system (glibc on Ubuntu 19.1) does this as well.  But not the shell's fault, anyway.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Re “ISO C contains no such requirement as this”: If the POSIX behavior is a subset of the C behavior (e.g., requires stderr be open when C does not), it is aligned in the sense intended.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Re “… C library, refusing to accept reads”: The failing `getc` is not evidence of POSIX non-compliance, as it occurs in `main`, after the C run-time startup has executed. stderr may have been readable at program startup (and may still be, through POSIX routines rather than C library routines).

Comment: `Is violating it Undefined Behavior?` Well, no. `And whose responsibility is it, the system's or the application's?` On the system. Doing `getc` and checking `ferror` doesn't mean the stream is not open for reading. But glibc has `__freadable` extension available and it reports `stderr` is not readable. I can't find anything related in [posix issue 6 rationale](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/download/c953.pdf) : /

Comment: Re “… even when FD 2 is open for reading and writing, trying to read from the stderr stream fails (if I want it to work, I have to use the FD directly). And that seems to be exactly what POSIX says isn't supposed to happen.”: Where does POSIX say stderr must be readable via C library routines?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The fact that it says the stderr **stream**, rather than the stderr **file descriptor**.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yeah, I think the proposed reading here is that "stream" means the `FILE *`, since that's what the rest of the page is about, and the only way I know of to read those is via `getc, fread, etc`.

Comment: By the way, OpenBSD 6.7 has the same behavior; `getc(stderr)` returns `EOF` and sets `errno` to `EBADF`, even though `read(2, buf, size)` succeeds.

Comment: You can try to prompt for a password by reading standard error. If you can't read standard error it's best to assume you aren't on a terminal after all. `/dev/tty` has been known to do something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Austin Group](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/) (the joint working group that maintains the POSIX standard) discussed the [defect that was reported about the "expected to be" wording](https://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1347) during the 2020-12-07 and 2020-12-10 telecons and agreed that the wording in POSIX Issue 7 (2018 edition) is problematic. The wording will  be changed in the next version of the POSIX standard as follows (copied from the [bug comment](https://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1347#c5161)):

> On page 65 before line 1912 (XBD "interactive shell") insert a new definition and renumber the remaining:
>
> > **Interactive Device**
> >
> > A terminal device.
> >
> > Note: This definition is intended to align with the ISO C standard's use of "interactive device".
>
> On page 496 lines 17224-17228 (XSH 2.5 Standard I/O Streams) and page 2017 lines 64723-64727 (XSH stderr, stdin, stdout DESCRIPTION) change:
>
> > At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output). When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.
>
> to:
>
> > At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and already open: *stdin* (standard input, for conventional input) for reading, *stdout* (standard output, for conventional output) for writing, and *stderr* (standard error, for diagnostic output) for writing. When opened, *stderr* shall not be fully buffered; *stdin* and *stdout* shall be fully buffered if and only if [CX]the file descriptor associated with the stream is determined not to be associated with an interactive device.[/CX]
>
> On page 2017 line 64733 (XSH stdin DESCRIPTION), change:
>
> > The *stderr* stream is expected to be open for reading and writing.
>
> to:
>
> > These file descriptors are often all associated with a single open file description which has access mode O_RDWR (e.g., in the case of a terminal device for a login shell). However, the *stderr*, *stdin*, and *stdout* streams need not be opened for both reading and writing at program start-up in this case.
>
> On page 2017 line 64747 (stdin SEE ALSO) add *isatty*().

Special thanks to Rich Felker for reporting the defect.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX elaborates on this in the [specification for `execve`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

> If file descriptor 0, 1, or 2 would otherwise be closed after a successful call to one of the exec family of functions, implementations may open an unspecified file for the file descriptor in the new process image. If a standard utility or a conforming application is executed with file descriptor 0 not open for reading or with file descriptor 1 or 2 not open for writing, the environment in which the utility or application is executed shall be deemed non-conforming, and consequently the utility or application might not behave as described in this standard.

For your own applications, they should be prepared for the possibility that the implementation opens new stdin/out/err for them if they try to exec with any of them closed, and can set their own rules (including deeming it a contract violation resulting in catastrophically wrong behavior) for how they handle it if the standard file descriptors are not open when they start.

For standard utilities, the above text covers it.

The [document you cited](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) just specifies that they're associated with those file descriptors. I agree it's not sufficiently clear, but the reasonable interpretation would be that, if the corresponding file descriptors are not open or not open for the appropriate modes at application entry, the results are those specified for that condition (typically EBADF) under the relevant functions. For example, `fgetc` specifies:

> [EBADF]
>
> [CX] [Option Start] The file descriptor underlying stream is not a valid file descriptor open for reading. [Option End]

Regarding the "expected to be" text:

> The stderr stream is expected to be open for reading and writing.

I don't think "expected to be" is defined anywhere in the standard. However, the word *stream* is used here, not file/file-descriptor, so I would read that as the `FILE` mode (as in `fopen` modes) for the `stderr` stream is such that neither read nor write functions on it produce undefined behavior as long as the rules about switching between them are honored. Without this text, e.g. in plain without POSIX on top, `fgetc(stderr)` would potentially produce undefined behavior.

Comment: That seems to be talking about bare file descriptors, not streams, and doesn't mention reading from stderr at all.

Comment: The document you cite just specifies that they're associated with those file descriptors. I agree it's not sufficiently clear, but the reasonable interpretation would be that, if the corresponding file descriptors are not open or not open for the appropriate modes at application entry, the results are those specified for that condition (typically `EBADF`).

Comment: But it specifically says "reading" in regards to standard error.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Updated with further interpretation.

Comment: The `EBADF` note makes the situation even stranger, because in my tests, file descriptor 2 *is* open for reading; you can do `read(2, buf, size)` and it succeeds.  Yet when you do `fgetc(stderr)`, it returns `EOF` with `errno == EBADF`.  Basically, it seems as though the C startup code is doing `stderr = fdopen(2, "w")` without regard to whether file descriptor 2 is open for reading or not.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Can you provide a complete test program doing that, possibly as a new question? At this point you're talking about random things that aren't in the question and I can't address them without seeing the actual program you're running, which might be doing other things affecting the result. Note you could also run it under `strace` to see what's going in.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/neldredge/6b33a31868b10f925585c2104a213c5c.  See comment at end of file for the output I'm getting.  Calling `read()` on fd 2 succeeds.  Calling `fgetc` on `stderr` fails with `errno == EBADF`, and strace shows that `fgetc` does not actually attempt to `read()` at all.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: My point is that you're talking about what happens when the relevant file descriptor (here 2) is not open for reading, but the fact that `read()` succeeds proves, I think, that it *is* open for reading.  So this does not help in explaining why `fgetc(stderr)` should fail.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ah, I get it now. You're testing with a valid fd 2 open for r+w. And indeed, it looks like this is due to glibc having `stderr` setup for write-only: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/stdfiles.c;h=b665a921160048629ab0b86e5022fd0d51d66688;hb=HEAD#l54. ISO C seems to have nothing to say on the matter of what modes the standard streams have, but POSIX seems to, as we found, specify r+w for `stderr` so this may be a conformance bug. The `EBADF` is synthesized based on the mode, but ok since if the mode doesn't admit writing, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Someone should probably open an issue on the tracker to discuss this. Do you want to, or should I?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Well, what's odd is that in my tests, OpenBSD and FreeBSD do exactly the same thing.  It would be surprising for POSIX to have specified something that conflicted with existing behavior on such a large fraction of existing implementations. and I haven't yet found one that does "comply".  That's why I'm wondering if we're misunderstanding something, or if the standard authors meant something else but didn't write it clearly, or if that provision is somehow just a mistake.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I've filed a request for interpretation/clarification with the standard: https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1347